# Overview of Combinatorial Technique of "Selberg’s Symmetry Formula"

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

In the paper entitled ["A Computational History of Prime Numbers and Riemann Zeros" (on page 4, click here)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.05244.pdf) it is written about "Selberg’s symmetry formula" that-

> Until 1950 it was widely believed (e.g., by Landau) that no such
>   elementary proof could be developed and so this result greatly
>   impressed the contemporaries. **Later Selberg extended this
>   combinatorial technique to show the PNT for primes in arithmetic
>   progression**, see [68]. For a nice survey see Diamond [18].
>   **Unfortunately, the high hopes placed in new insights coming from finding an elementary proof of PNT were thwarted**.

Can anyone give an overview (informally as much as possible) of combinatorial technique of "Selberg’s symmetry formula"?

**PS:** Why the high hopes placed in new insights coming from finding an elementary proof of PNT were thwarted? What was actually expected from the elementary proof (since the proof of PNT is already discovered at that time)?

Comment: I think the main motivation (and certainly Selberg's motivation) for finding alternative proofs of the PNT was to make progress on the Riemann Hypothesis. Just as the Riemann zeta serves the primes, perhaps the primes can also serve the Riemann zeta...  BTW Selberg's paper is only 13 pages long, why don't you read it?

Comment: @GHfromMO I fear that 13 page long paper requires 13 months of  study!! We are still learning .. for example we two are wondering how an elementary proof can help to Reiman's Hypothesis...

Comment: The prime number theorem with a certain error term yields a certain zero-free region for the Riemann (not Reiman) zeta function, and vice versa. So the hope was that a new proof of the prime number theorem will yield a new zero-free region for the Riemann zeta function. You can learn basic analytic number theory from many textbooks, please do that before asking questions here (as this site is meant for research level questions).

Comment: @GHfromMO thanks! now I understand, I hope my friend will do, yes we are aware that it is a research forum, that is why we didn't ask any question here instead of MSE, why do u think that? Anyway , can u give us the overview?

Comment: I cannot give you an overview. I recommend that you study the paper.

Comment: @GHfromMO I read the proof (source: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2006/PAPERS/Balady.pdf), except one part (see the post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3859514/deriving-the-symmetry-formula-of-selberg-prime-number-theorem), I understood everything, but I don't see anything combinatorial, I also read  the "Selberg’s asymptotic formula" in the book  IntroductiontoAnalytic Number Theory by of Tom M. Apostol,skimmed through Selberg's original paper, nothing about combinatorics is mentioned. Could you plz point out which part is combinatorial in Selberg's Symmetry Formula?

Comment: I did not say the proof is combinatorial. All I said it is 13 pages long, so you can read it and see it for yourself.